# How many cylinders in a cube

Tags: mathematics, geometry, packing

Could someone please help me with this math question:

How many cylinders with a diameter of $7.44 cm$ and a height of $4.9 cm$ can fit in a cube of $1m \times 1m \times 1m$?

Comment: Can the cylinders be deformed or modified or broken? If not then it's a matter of cylinder stacking optimization and math. (Both of which are kind of off topic)

Comment: No they can't be broken or modified. I realise now that this question is better suited for the math stack exchange. Thanks anyhow :)

Comment: No problem. And I bet they'll argue about the answer there too. ;)